# Perl not inheriting base methods

Tags: perl, inheritance

I have a module that is acting as the base for several others:

```
package P::Hb2::BaseMetric;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->init(ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH' ? @_ : {@_});
    return $self;
}

sub init {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    foreach (keys %{$args}) {
        $self->{$_} = $args->{$_};
    }
    return $self;
} 

sub mark {
    die "Metric not implemented.";
}

1;
```

I'm trying to inherit from it with this:

```
package P::Hb2::CPUInfo;

use strict;
use warnings;
use P::Hb2Utils;
use base 'P::Hb2::BaseMetric';

sub mark {
    my $self = shift;
    my $time = `date +%s` * 1000;
    my $stats = (split /\n/, `iostat -c 1 2`)[-1];

    $stats =~ /(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(\s+)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/;
    my %nice = (name => 'sys.cpu.iostat.nice.percent', datapoints => [[$time, $4]], tags => {});
    my %idle = (name => 'sys.cpu.iostat.idle.percent', datapoints => [[$time, $12]], tags => {});
    my %steal = (name => 'sys.cpu.iostat.steal.percent', datapoints => [[$time, $10]], tags => {});
    my %user = (name => 'sys.cpu.iostat.user.percent', datapoints => [[$time, $2]], tags => {});
    my %iowait = (name => 'sys.cpu.iostat.iowait.percent', datapoints => [[$time, $8]], tags => {});
    my %system = (name => 'sys.cpu.iostat.system.percent', datapoints => [[$time, $6]], tags => {});
    my @metrics;

    push @metrics, \%nice;
    push @metrics, \%idle;
    push @metrics, \%steal;
    push @metrics, \%user;
    push @metrics, \%iowait;
    push @metrics, \%system;
    return \@metrics;
}

1;
```

and trying to call it with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

require P::Hb2::CPUInfo;

my $ref = P::Hb2::CPUInfo->new({hello => "world"});
my @metric = $ref->mark();

print Dumper($ref);
print Dumper(\@metric);
```

But when i do this I get the error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "P::Hb2::CPUInfo" at test.pl line 9.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere do you load the `P::Hb2::BaseMetric` class (assuming it does not live in the `P::Hb2Utils` file). Suggested fix: Change `use base ...` to `use parent ...`, as this auto-loads the file for that class.

Also, the `base` pragma is being phased out – it is *only* relevant in combination with the `fields` pragma, an ill-guided attempt towards easier OOP.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm stuck using a pretty old perl where parent isn't available.

Comment: You should be able to install `parent` from CPAN on older perls.

Comment: base autoloads as well. The primary difference between base and parent is that base can fail silently.